# How is the IoT Edge Deployment JSON used?

Tags: json, azure-iot-edge

I've created an IoT Edge Deployment through the Azure portal and everything deployed just fine. However, at the end of the deployment steps, I was given a JSON document generated from the Edge Hub with all of my configuration settings. I would like to take that document and use it to deploy the same configuration in a different Azure environment. Is there currently a way to use the generated JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand Azure IoT Edge deployments, you can refer to [Deploy and monitor IoT Edge modules at scale - preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-monitor)

To reuse the generated json for the deployment, you can keep a local copy of that file (or maintain your copies from skeleton) and then use that file to create deployments to different IoT Edge devices. You might refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vscode-develop-csharp-module) to see how do that is VS Code from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. The second doc you linked was what I needed. I was using [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module) and the first doc you linked but they both only mention using the portal to deploy the modules.